# Adding tags to products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, tags

what is the code needed to insert tags to a product in Magento?

thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO! People here will most likely be glad to help, but **you must show some effort** : many will be OK to help with a specific question/problem, but won't agree to just *give you the code*.

Comment: Ok, I need to know the name of ORM entity class to insert a tag to a product.

Answer (score 5):

```
    $tagName = 'php';
    $customerID = NULL;
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $productID = 1;

    $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tagModel->loadByName($tagName);
    //$tagModel->unsetData()->loadByName($tagName);  //if using a loop 

    if (!$tagModel->getId()) {
             $tagModel->setName($tagName)
                      ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
                      ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                      ->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())
                      ->save();
   }

   $relationStatus = $tagModel->saveRelation($productId, $customerId, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento Developer have the option to allow customers to tag your products. When a customer tags a certain product, the tag appears as pending and must be approved before it can show up on the product page.

Let's add a tag to our product, approve it and see how it then shows up on the product page. To add a tag to a product, simply write the tag word in the Add Your Tags: field available on the product page and click Add Tags. We'll add "Great" as a tag. A confirmation message will show up saying that the tag has been accepted for moderation:

Magento New Tag

Now go to your Magento admin area > Catalog > Tags > Pending Tags to view all your pending tags. In our case, there will be only one pending tag for the word "Great":

Magento Pending Tags

Click it and you will be taken to a page where you can change the status of the tag. It will appear as "Pending", so le't change it to "Approved" and click Save Tag.

Now that the tag has been approved, all other customers will see it on the product page.

You can also manage tags on a per-product basis. Go to your Magento admin area > Catalog > Manage Products and click the product the tags of which you want to check. Then from the left menu click Product Tags and you will see all the tags for that product.

Answer (score 0):

That is default magento functionality. Catalog->Tags in backend.

Comment: ok, but I need to insert the tags directly from a php script.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the place how it's already done in Magento. See at the `saveAction` method in the `Mage_Tag_IndexController` class (`app/code/core/Mage/Tag/controllers/IndexController.php`)