# adding tags to products in magento not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using the following stackoverflow answer to create tags and add products to them.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570913/4419217

Unfortunately, the tags are just appearing in the tags tab of the product (in the backend).

They are not on the frontend product page (even after emptying all caches and reindexing) and if I "open a tag" in the backend, there are no assigned products.

How can that happen?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I changed the code behind that link that the status is right away approved instead of pending.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the RWD theme which does not include Product Tags by default. Here's how to add them to the RWD theme:

**Step 1:**

- Copy the tags template files to your theme
- Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag`
- Copy the entire `/tag` folder to:
  -`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template`

**Note that you may have a custom package instead of 'rwd' and you should have a custom theme name instead of 'default'**

**Step 2:**

- Add the XML call to your layout
  open `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/tag.xml` change the following code from:

> ```
> <!-- Remove all tags functionality from theme layout -->
> ```

to:

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
     <label>Catalog Product View</label>
      <!-- Mage_Tag -->
     <reference name="product.info.additional">
         <block type="tag/product_list" name="product_tag_list" before="-" template="tag/list.phtml">
             <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.tag.list.list.before" as="list_before"
 translate="label">
                 <label>Tags List Before</label>
                 <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
             </block>
         </block>
     </reference> 
  </catalog_product_view>
```

**Note that you may have a custom package instead of 'rwd' and you should have a custom theme name instead of 'default'**

If you don't know which package/theme you are using you can check in the admin under `System->Configuration->Design(left column)->Package(tab) & Theme(tab)`.

You may need to flush you Magento caches to see the changes. In the admin go to `System->Cache Management` and flush all Magento caches. Now refresh your website and you should see the tags show up near the bottom of the page below the Upsell Products.